# Access to the callback function of checkbox

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have some checkbox and a push button to select all of them.

Code of my button "Select all" :

```
for i = 1:5
      set(sprintf('handles.check%d',i),'value', 1)
end
```

But, I would like to go to the checkbox callback function each time I select one of them. How can I do this ? Because for the moment, all my check box are selected when I push the button "Select all" but the code into each checkbxo is not executed. My code in a checkbox is :

```
function check1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    if(get(hObject ,'Value') == 1)
       ind=1;
       assignin('base','ind',ind);
    end
 end
```

Comment: You mean, the callback is not executed if the checkbox is checked not by click, but by some code, right?

Comment: yes, if I check only one chekbox, the callback is executed but if I select all the checkbox with my pushbutton, the callback is never executed.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way then is to call the callback functions manually in the `for` loop after the `set` command.

Comment: Looks like it is the only way. The callback is called only when triggered by the "end user".

Comment: Ok but how can I call my functions callback ? because they have some inputs (hObject, eventdata, handles) ..

Comment: `eventdata` and `handles` can be passed from your `select all` callback. `hObject` is the handle to the actual checkbox, thus `handles.check...`.

Comment: hObject is the handle to the checkbox. The others seem to not be used by your callback, so I guess you can pass empty values.. Here is some discussion you might find useful: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162058

Comment: Thank you, it works if I put a callback to just one checkbox like this:

`check1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)`

But I would like to call all my check box so in a loop, I want to change my indice but I don't know how to write it ...

Comment: Just use `feval(sprintf('check%d_Callback',i),handles.(sprintf('check%d',i)),eventdata,handles)` (just recheck for syntax errors, I didn't run the code)